# How to implement a counter in for loop for a bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, counter

I can't find my answer anywhere. The counter in my code doesn't work. Why and what to do ?

```
count=0;
for file1 in folder1;
do
    cat $file1 | while read line
    do
        echo $line;
        ((count++));
    done
done
echo "Count : ${count}";
```

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @Cyrus Indeed, this site is useful. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a pipeline, the commands are executed in a subshell. Changes in a subshell don't propagate to the parent shell, so the counter is never incremented.

You don't need a pipeline here. Use a redirection instead:

```bash
    count=0
    while read line
    do
        echo $line;
        ((count++));
    done < "$file1"
```

Comment: This solution works only if there is something in the read variable, If the value in read is null, the count is 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @Robin: Did you initialize `count=0` before entering the loop?